# I need to access localstorage or cookie from within the serviceworker

Tags: service-worker, progressive-web-apps

I wish to make a fetch call after the push event for fetching the notif data through an internal api with user specific params which are stored in the localstorage or cookie such as usertype or country id .. how do i do this ?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You cannot use Local Storage in service workers. It was decided that service workers should not have access to any synchronous APIs. You can use IndexedDB instead, or communicate with the controlled page using `postMessage()`.

By default, cookies are not included with `fetch` requests, but you can include them as follows: `fetch(url, {credentials: 'include'})`.

Comment: credentials include worked like a charm .. thanks....!!saviour for now .. but for the long run will have to get into making an indexed db ..thanks a lot buddy

Comment: @amansatija check out [localforage](https://github.com/mozilla/localForage), which supports both plus WebSQL for no extra effort.