# How to use httpOnly session in serviceWorker with fetch?

Tags: cors, service-worker, fetch-api

I want to create logic similar to facebook notifications. When my site is not opened in tab user gonna receive Notification from service worker. So the idea is trigger restful service from setInterval in serviceWorker

Ok great. The first issue I faced that `XmlHttpRequest` is not available in serviceWorker. That leaves me the only choice: use [fetch api](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API). My site uses httpOnly session cookie for authorization. So I tried to call fetch with `credentials: 'same-origin'`.

```
fetch('https://localhost:8000/get_extension_messages', {
        credentials: 'same-origin'
    }).then(function (response) {
        console.log(e);
    }).catch(function(e) {
        console.error(e);
    })
```

I added `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: https://localhost:8000/` to server response but my request doesn't event reach it, the only thing I get `sw.js TypeError: Failed to fetch`. According to [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch):

> A fetch() promise will reject with a TypeError when a network error is
>   encountered or CORS is misconfigured on the server side, although this
>   usually means permission issues or similar — a 404 does not constitute
>   a network error, for example.
>   [image]

It's worth to mention that this code works from webpage which means I configured CORS ok. Since my cookie is httpOnly I can't  even access it from webpage (well I can write a method that returns sessionid and then pass sessionid from webpage to serviceworker but it doesn't feel right).

So my questions are:

- How do I implement such use-case?
- Can I execute fetch from service worker and read the response, am I doing something wrong?

**UPDATE**:

It turns out that self-signed certificate caused `TypeError`. The interesting fact if I run chrome without any flags, service worker doesn't load at all. In my case I started chrome with `--allow-insecure-localhost --user-data-dir=/tmp/lol`, so service worker worked without any issues, but fetch api didn't.

Comment: Probably related but it doesn't work https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34589972/i-need-to-access-localstorage-or-cookie-from-within-the-serviceworker/34594459#34594459

Comment: Any solution to this, years later?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if it's a typo, but the Access-Control-Allow-Origin response header should not include the trailing slash - it should simply be:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: https://localhost:8000
```

That **could** be the problem.

Comment: It turned out ssl cased the issue, I explained in my question. The weird thing that chrome didn't even make a request to server to verify ssl, it simply treated webpage certificate as non-valid and decided to return "TypeError" in promise immediately. That makes impossible to test serviceWorker while development, because you can't create certificate to localhost. Thanks for your answer tho, I will keep in mind that `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` shouldn't have trailing slash.